# How to debug Weka in Eclipse

Tags: weka

I am trying to compile the weka and run its GUI in a debug mode to see logic flows of a certain algorithm in action.

But I think it needs to put in the right arguments into the RunWeka execution, which I have no ideas of what arguments I need to put in the Eclipse's debug configuration's argument panel.

Anyone could provide what configurations are needed before debugging the Weka, and get the GUI running in debug mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose weka.gui.GUIChooser as starting point in your eclipse run/debug configuration. Then you can easily choose your break point and start debugging.

[image: Weka Debug]